# USB Drive Removed While Write Now GParted Hangs

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I was writing to drive with UNetbootin. This is the error on attempted mount:

```
Failed to open directory "0FFD-2516".

Error when getting information for file '/media/0FFD-2516/╛▌ü╞ΦÇ.Sfì': Input/output error.
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tried writing to the USB drive with UnetBootin, it's safe to assume that it held no important data, and formatting it now shouldn't be a big deal. Create a file system, FAT32 or NTFS, and it should work again.

Comment: Since UNetbootin won't create a filesystem, **if** the next use of the drive will be to take an image written by UNetbootin, it should be formatted FAT32. (NTFS doesn't make a good filesystem for a bootable flash drive holding a Linux system.)

Comment: I had to format with Windows as Linux would not mount.